# Prevent outside users from accessing my local machine (using Node.js) in a coffeeshop?

Tags: mac, node.js

I have a node server running on port 8080. This is for some personal development and I'm accessing my web server using localhost in my chrome browser. I'm sitting in a coffeeshop and I don't want outside users to have access to my files on my webserver.

So how do I prevent all users that are not localhost from accessing this web server? is it a node.js setting or a system setting (I'm using a mac). Thanks.

Comment: Do you want "localhost-only" all the time or only when outside your home network?

Comment: only outside my apartment. in my apartment I want to be able to access this from mobile devices. so only in the coffeeshop i want to restrict to localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of blocking everything from a firewall, why not just have it bind to `127.0.0.1`? Nothing, but things on the local machine, would be able to access it then.

This can be done with `express` by doing:

```
app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

or with `http`:

```
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this by going into

System Preferences -> Security Preferences -> Firewall -> Firewall Options -> Block all incoming connections